# what is the best way to create a 3 independent column layout which can wrap

Tags: css, flexbox, multiple-columns, wrapper

I am new on this forum, hopefully someone can help me out.

I am trying to create a page with three independent columns. Each column will have its own divs of different heights. See this image - [3 columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bv0S4.png)

I achieved this layout using separate divs for each column and then divs for each window, then I tried to make the layout wrap when I make the screen smaller into two then three columns but this is where I got stuck. I want it to prioritise the top divs when the window gets smaller, see this image - [2 columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWdvf.png). Wrapping is of course made very simple with flex and grid but these two don't allow me to create different height divs in each column, it's always based on even horizontal lines, or if I use flex in column direction it messes up the order of windows when it wraps.

I am very particular about the order being as per the image, because I will need to keep adding content to the page and most recent content will need to always be at the top.

Maybe there is a way to add order to each div in flex which reaches beyond its container? Or can someone suggest another way to do it?

Hope this is clear enough...
Thanks

Comment: There is a library called Masonry which does exactly this https://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: This looks great, however, does it allow to create the lines between each column? All layouts that use masonry seem to be very pinterest-like, so each 'window' is floating freely without any lines in between them.